# Can an audio file contain line breaks?

Tags: string, sockets, special-characters, line-breaks

From what I understand, \r\n are special characters (correct?). Is there any possibility that an audio file can contain line breaks?

What I'm trying to do is send both line broken strings and full audio files to my socket and I'm just curious if detecting line breaks will ever stop me in the middle of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An audio file may contain any byte or byte sequence, so trying to detect any specific sequence in the middle of the stream is bound to fail eventually. If we assume the audio is essentially random, the odds of any 2-byte sequence equaling `\r\n` is about 1/65536.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only solution I can think of to fully avoid this is to open an additional socket for the file transfer and keep the line breaking strings to send commands back and forth. Thanks again.

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88, that's a good idea, it's the way FTP works.

Comment: Yep. that's where I got the idea from actually

Answer (score 2):

What's a "special character"? There is no such thing except in some relative sense you specify. Your audio stream might well contain bytes with value 10 (\n) or 13 (\r). You need some way to distinguish text from audio data in your stream other than looking for newlines.

Answer (score 0):

A line break is just chr(11) (or some other number). Your data will likely contain a byte with a value of 11. However, you shouldn't be converting it to characters anyway, just read it as a byte.

But yeah, injecting line breaks would corrupt the file, but if you just read is as a stream of bytes treated as bytes you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Interpretation of line break bytes only applies when processing textual data.  Audio is binary data instead.  You should not be processing audio as text.